# symbol's function definition is void: after-load'

Tags: elisp

Upon cloning the codes

[emacs.d/init-org.el at 9bb862b3d5f95d66506693cf1ebc685bb79d1080 · purcell/emacs.d](https://github.com/purcell/emacs.d/blob/9bb862b3d5f95d66506693cf1ebc685bb79d1080/lisp/init-org.el#L290-L308)

to the personal configuration,

```
;;; Org clock

;; Save the running clock and all clock history when exiting Emacs, load it on startup
(after-load 'org
  (org-clock-persistence-insinuate))
(setq org-clock-persist t)
(setq org-clock-in-resume t)

;; Save clock data and notes in the LOGBOOK drawer
(setq org-clock-into-drawer t)
;; Save state changes in the LOGBOOK drawer
(setq org-log-into-drawer t)
;; Removes clocked tasks with 0:00 duration
(setq org-clock-out-remove-zero-time-clocks t)

;; Show clock sums as hours and minutes, not "n days" etc.
(setq org-time-clocksum-format
      '(:hours "%d" :require-hours t :minutes ":%02d" :require-minutes t))
```

It prompt that `symbol's function definition is void: after-load'

Search keyword 'afterf-load`, it return  with-eval-after-load  [Hooks for Loading - GNU Emacs Lisp Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Hooks-for-Loading.html)

Does after-load is a personal defined funtion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, this is not a symbol which is defined in the standard library. The repo you have cloned  defines this as a portability alias for `with-eval-after-load` in [`init-utils`](https://github.com/purcell/emacs.d/blob/master/lisp/init-utils.el) but of course you have to load this definition before you can use it. Probably review the repo's installation and usage instructions.